# Is this PRNG-function secure?

Tags: php, prng

I have to have a cryptographically secure function,that gives me a random string, for encryption. Is the following function good enough for this?

'PHP'

```
function GenerateRandomString($Length) {
 $Length /= 2;
 $cstrong = false;
 while ($cstrong != TRUE){
    $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($Length, $cstrong);
 }
 $hex = bin2hex($bytes);
 return $hex;
}
```

Comment: It's using a good source of randomness, yes. But I don't know whether `$cstrong` will suddenly turn from `false` to `true` if you try repeatedly. Most likely you'll just get into an infinite loop.

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @deceze I moved this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59096/random-string-generator-using-openssl-in-php